# How do I get complex datatypes stored in an HBase value byte[]

Tags: java, api, hbase

```
 for (Result result = scanner.next(); (result != null); result = scanner.next()) {       
        for(Cell cell : result.listCells()) {           
            System.out.println(Value=" + Bytes.toString(cell.getValue())); 
        }
    }
```

I can determine if the datatype of the cell's value is a primitive java type. However I've discovered that the cell's value byte[] can store a variety of types like json, pdf, or images. I'm having difficulty determining the aforementioned datatypes.

Comment: I agree with @kichik but common practice is you have to maintain a document of what columnfamily/column data types you have and based on that you need to convert those to your known format

Answer (score 2):

HBase stores nothing but bytes. It is up to you to decide what those bytes mean. Usually you'd have a convention like everything is JSON, or certain column names have certain types, or even certain column families.